# What to do to change materialized view column size when under line table column size changed?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

What to do to change materialized view column size when under line table column size changed? This is oracle 11gR2 db on Linux. I tried recompile the MV, it didn't work. Please do not auto migrate this question to another database site, I want to stay here in stackoverflow.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `alter materialized view my_mv modify (my_column varchar2(new_size));`?

Comment: good idea, let me try, thx!

Comment: to answer Adam question when do mv recompile, nothing changed...

Comment: Jonearles, if you enter the same thing as an answer, then I will mark your answer as THE Answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you alter the table you must also alter the materialized view.

```
--Create simple table and materialized view
create table test1(a varchar2(1 char));
create materialized view mv_test1 as select a from test1;

--Increase column width of column in the table
alter table test1 modify (a varchar2(2 char));

--Insert new value that uses full size
insert into test1 values('12');

--Try to compile and refresh the materialized view
alter materialized view mv_test1 compile;
begin
    dbms_mview.refresh(user||'.MV_TEST1');
end;
/

ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path
ORA-12899: value too large for column "JHELLER"."MV_TEST1"."A" (actual: 2, maximum: 1)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2563
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2776
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2745
ORA-06512: at line 3

--Increase column width of column in the materialized view and refresh
alter materialized view mv_test1 modify (a varchar2(2 char));
begin
    dbms_mview.refresh(user||'.MV_TEST1');
end;
/
select * from mv_test1;
A
--
12
```